# Geo SQL to find points near location

Tags: mysql, sql, geo, gtfs

I using the below sql:

based on http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

```
SELECT * , 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( (
- 36.8812573 - abs( stop_lat ) ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( - 36.8812573 * pi( ) /180 ) * COS( abs( stop_lat ) * pi( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( 174.63832160000004 - stop_lon ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) )
) AS distance
FROM stops
HAVING distance <100
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

To find stops that are within a radius of my current lat and lon.

I am using GTFS data and the schema is below. (The lat and lon and last two columns)

```
01  7106    210 Victoria St     -36.8481990     174.7544900
0002    7108    220 Victoria St     -36.8481710     174.7523800
0003    7110    36 College Hill     -36.8485220     174.7485400
0004    7112    68 College Hill     -36.8479760     174.7466700
0005    7114    2 Jervois Rd    -36.8471670     174.7437800
0006    7116    90 Jervois Rd   -36.8453760     174.7408300
0007    7118    160 Jervois Rd  -36.8453250     174.7373100
0008    7120    206 Jervois Rd  -36.8454990     174.7354500
0009    7122    270 Jervois Rd  -36.8474010     174.7321400
0012    7121    203 Jervois Rd  -36.8473770     174.7319200
0013    7119    165 Jervois Rd  -36.8454100     174.7348400
```

The table structure like this:

[image]

As far as I can see, the query should return some results. However it doesn't. Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

*** Update ***********

I noticed that I was missing the temp output table name, so I am now getting some results. However, they start at 5000 distance from my location. Any ideas?

Updated SQL:

```
SELECT * , 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( (
- 36.8812573 - abs( stop_lat ) ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( - 36.8812573 * pi( ) /180 ) * COS( abs( stop_lat ) * pi( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( ( 174.63832160000004 - stop_lon ) * pi( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) )
) AS distance
FROM stops dest
HAVING distance <5100
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please elaborate on the formula used. There are quite a few magic numbers, and the units are not specified.

Comment: Btw, specifying your current location as magic numbers is not a good idea either (even less so for the purpose of understanding).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev formula reference link

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev What do you mean by magic numbers? The variables in the eq are lon and lat.

Comment: -36.8812573 , 174.63832160000004 (your current coordinates), 3956 (Earth radius in miles).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Ah, got you. Next I will make sure to clarify these. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the formula is the culprit. Even if you took it from a reliable source and made no errors in implementing, there can e.g. be a unit confusion.

- There's an error: `abs` is never needed, there's no such thing in [the ‘haversine’ formula](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/visual/home/proj/tiger/gisfaq.html). In the 2nd case, it doesn't change anything as `cos` is an even function, but in the 1st case, it does.