# Geospatial using maria db

Tags: mariadb, geospatial, mariasql, mariadb-connect-engine

I need to select all points that is within 30 KM radius as a circle from a specific latitude/longitude using maria db.

For example:

```
latitude = 46.8167
longitude = 6.9333
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geo SQL to find points near location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872384/geo-sql-to-find-points-near-location)

Comment: I am new to maria db . I found a lot of geometric relations like ST_DISTANCE,ST_WITHIN etc. Is it possible to do with this.

Comment: No. They use cartesian distance while you need distance on a sphere.

Comment: I need the distance in sphere. Sorry i didn't mention that in question.